# Change Powershell Foreground colour for hadoop command or suppress the info

Tags: powershell, hadoop

I'm creating a teststack that makes use of some hadoop commands, more specifically I'm copying some files from s3 and also formatting the namenode.

I'm trying to either suppress the output, send it to a file or change the colour of the displayed text as it currently shows up as red.

Currently I'm working with this:

```
    #Copy the models that are required for the streaming job - AWS installed on AMI.
$HOST.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor  = "Yellow"
write-host "Updating the jar with application.conf"
& 7z u c:\jarname.jar c:\jarname\application.conf 

write-host "Downloadingfrom s3" 
& hadoop fs -cp s3n://files /tmp
$HOST.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor  = "White"
```

The foreground colour options are a recent addition and are not respected by the commands as it still shows up in red.

The reason why is that the testers look out for red as errors.

Any suggestions would be fantastic, thanks in advance

Comment: What part of the output is wrong color or to be supressed? Would `|out-null` do?

Comment: @vonPryz - thanks for taking the time to look.  The entirety of the hadopp output would ideally be suppressed (unless it errors)
I'll try the | out-null you suggested

Comment: @vonPryz out-null has no effect :(

Answer (score 1):

-foreground color will work if the only issue is making the output pretty, however it will still look strange for anyone using a non-default config.  Ideally you want to redirect the output from the error stream to the standard output stream, which you can do like this

```
& hadoop fs -cp s3n://files /tmp > 4>&1
```

you can find additional information on stream redirection here - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -ForegroundColor with the write-host  like this

`write-host "Updating the jar with application.conf"
& 7z u c:\jarname.jar c:\jarname\application.conf -ForegroundColor Yellow`